# position divs like keys on a keyboard

Tags: css

It's been a few hours that i'm trying to align 4 div like they are aligned on the keyboard, but i can't make it work...

I don't want it to be absolute, because i have 3 sets of four div.
Those div are supposed to be on the left of a page where I have a canvas, they are basically the instructions for my javascript game.

here is my code :

```css
p.keyboard {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #5E5E5E;
    font: bold 10px arial;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 7.5px 10px;
    background: #EFF0F2;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-top: 1px solid #F5F5F5;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 25px #E8E8E8, 0 1px 0 #C3C3C3, 0 2px 0 #C9C9C9, 0 2px 3px #333;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #F5F5F5;
}
```

```html
<div id="green">
  <p class="keyboard">Z</p>
  <p class="keyboard">Q</p>
  <p class="keyboard">S</p>
  <p class="keyboard">D</p>
</div>
<div id="blue">      
  <p class="keyboard">Flèche haut</p>           
  <p class="keyboard">Flèche gauche</p>
  <p class="keyboard">Flèche bas</p>
  <p class="keyboard">Flèche droite</p>
</div>
<div id="red">
  <p class="keyboard">O</p>
  <p class="keyboard">K</p>
  <p class="keyboard">L</p>
  <p class="keyboard">M</p>
</div>
```

I've tried multiple things, with multiple div tags everywhere, using flexbox or not, but i'm clearly not good enough ^^".
I basically want the "Z", the "O" and the "flèche haut" above the three others and centered.

Thanks for any help...

Comment: You could probably use a table while using negative margins... But be aware, that French people have AZERTY, while Czech people have QWERTZ and most of the rest have QWERTY.

Comment: well, a couple of divs with display: flex should work as well. But it's a bit fiddly ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I wouldn't use `<p>` tags. Being treated as `paragraph`s, most browsers will add styles to them which you will need to reset.

It's better to use a more generic tag, like `<span>` or a `<div>`.

That being said here's my attempt at it, using `flexbox`:

```css
.keys > span {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #5E5E5E;
    font: bold 10px arial;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 3px 2px;
    padding: 7.5px 10px;
    background: #EFF0F2;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-top: 1px solid #F5F5F5;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 25px #E8E8E8, 0 1px 0 #C3C3C3, 0 2px 0 #C9C9C9, 0 2px 3px #333;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #F5F5F5;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
}
.keyboard {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}
.keys {
  display: flex; 
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 0 1 100%;
  padding: .5rem;
}
.keys > span:first-child {
  flex: 0 0 0;
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-right: 50%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#green { background-color: rgba(0,255,0,.35);}
#red { background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.35);}
#blue { background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.35);}
```

```html
<div class="keyboard">
  <div id="green" class="keys">
    <span>Z</span>
    <span>Q</span>
    <span>S</span>
    <span>D</span>
  </div>
  <div id="blue" class="keys">
    <span>Flèche haut</span>           
    <span>Flèche gauche</span>
    <span>Flèche bas</span>
    <span>Flèche droite</span>
  </div>
  <div id="red" class="keys">
    <span>O</span>
    <span>K</span>
    <span>L</span>
    <span>M</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The bigger keys seem missaligned, but it's because 2nd and 4th are not equal. The first one is actually centered.
You'll note I also streamlined your markup a bit. When all the items of a parent have a `class`, it makes sense to apply the class to their parent and style them using

```
.parent-class > child {}
```

If you need more help with the layout itself, feel free to share a jsFiddle link and I'll have a look if you have any trouble positioning elements.

Don't forget to [`autoprefix`](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).